Can you change the base point in an iterated wedge sum?
I have a question about the definition of a wedge sum of topological spaces.
Consider the statement "The space $X$ has the homotopy type of a wedge sum of spheres."
I am curious whether the statement should be considered to be true when $X$ is, e.g., a disjoint union of two circles.
We could obtain $X$ (up to homotopy equivalence) by taking $S^0$, wedging one point with a copy of $S^1$, then wedging the resulting space at the other point of $S^0$ with another copy of $S^1$.
But does this space count as a wedge sum of spheres?
Of course, each path component of $X$ has the homotopy type of a wedge sum of spheres. But I am unsure about how to think about base points if we are iterating a wedge sum.

"Wedge sum of spheres" means with a single wedge point. It also happens to be the case that if the spaces you're wedging are path-connected you can wedge at different points, e.g. the wedge of $3$ circles is the same up to homotopy whether you wedge all at one point or wedge them in a line at two different points (in a "chain" pattern). But a disjoint union of circles is not obtained in this way at all; why are you talking about $S^0$?

One should think of the wedge sum as the coproduct in the category $\mathrm{Top}_*$ of topological spaces equipped with a basepoint and basepoint-preserving continuous functions between them; given a family of pointed spaces $(X_i, x_i)_{i \in I}$, it's then defined to be the pointed space
$$
    \bigvee_{i \in I} (X_i, x_i) = \bigg(\coprod_{i \in I} X_i\bigg) \big/ \bigcup_{i \in I}\, \{x_i\}
$$
pointed at the class of the identified basepoints, which is what we usually call the "wedge point."
This is generally what people have in mind when they talk about wedge sums, even though they do not always state it clearly. In particular, we do not consider $S^1 \sqcup S^1$ to have the homotopy type of a wedge sum of spheres.
As Qiaochu Yuan points out in the comments, sometimes it does not matter whether you wedge at one or at multiple points, for instance if all the spaces involved are connected CW-complexes, but for disconnected spaces it really does matter, and so does the choice of basepoint: Take the wedge sum of $S^2 \sqcup S^1$ with itself pointed at a point in $S^1$ as compared to the one where the wedge point is chosen in $S^2$.
